# Selenium Grid - Python File Path

Tags: python, linux, windows, selenium, selenium-grid

I have been working on a test script for a while and found what I think is an issue I can't solve. From research I found that the tests are run on the host machine not the nodes this is fine until I want to check a file has downloaded into a directory I use Linux as my development machine and windows are my node machines so the path is formatted for Linux and looks on the host machine not the node. Here is my code that gets the path.

```
os.path.isfile(os.path.expanduser('~') + '/Downloads/mpdf.pdf')
```

This is the path I get back

```
/home/ben/Downloads/mpdf.pdf
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could get the path from the node machine and check for a file.

Comment: it's all subjective, but if i were you, i'd make a web service that the nodes put all files too, that way files won't be on one particular node.  it's much easier to manage that way.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable idea just don't want to spend ages developing something that works for a small part of tests.

Comment: think about the long run though - if all your downloaded files are in a collective place - it'd be worth it :)  custom solutions like this are much more efficient and effective.  consider it an investment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with to avoid building more complexity than was needed was not do download the file but run a link and check if it was successful with the status code of 200.

```
responce = urllib2.urlopen('http://address.co/download')
assert responce.getcode() == 200
```

This is my solution and it seems to work and I don't need to download the file any more that is better on the bandwidth of the server I am running my tests on.